# Database Tool with good Interface for Reusing user-created Queries

Tags: database, database-administration

I am looking for a tool that would help me easily reuse queries.

What should it be like?

You type a query like `Select * FROM person where name LIKE ${name}`
And you would like to re-use this type of query next time like invocation of some function with parameter/s like `personWithNameLike(P)` or `personWithNameLike(name=p}`

Is there any tool that could help me in any way?

Comment: "*And U would like reuse*" - Pleeease use complete words and somewhat correct grammar.

Comment: What type of database are you using? (MySql, Postgres, etc.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read about how to setup [stored procedures](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stored_procedure) for your version of SQL (if supported).

A stored procedure lets you define what should be done (eg: a query), the expected input and output and then you can 'call' the procedure just as you describe.